# Making python output print and disappear?

Tags: python

Hey i wanted to know that if there is a way to make a python output print and disappear like in the case of comparing a user entered word with a world in a list,while quickly printing all the words it has traversed ,quite like a animation?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If you want to do it in a console, use `os.system('clear')", which will clear the whole console output. If you want a nice animation, it is better to develop a GUI

Comment: is `import os` , `os.system("cls")` meets your needs?..or do you need more advanced?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try to do is clear the console. There are multiple resources on how to do it so I won't explain it here, but it's easy to find on the internet. If you have a bunch of text in the console and there's a specific piece of text that you want to delete, then you can get all of the text in the console as a string and filter out the part that you want to delete, so that way, when you clear the console, you can re-print that back into the console, so that way it disappears but all of the other text elements do not. If that makes sense lol.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to **Amirul Akmal** I believe this code might Help you understand it better

```
from os import system
# import sleep to show output for some time period 
from time import sleep 

# define our clear function 
def clear(): 

    # for windows 
    if name == 'nt': 
        _ = system('cls') 

    # for mac and linux(here, os.name is 'posix') 
    else: 
        _ = system('clear') 

# print out some text 
print('test\n'*10) 
# sleep for 2 seconds after printing output 
sleep(2) 
# now call function we defined above 
clear()
```